# A question about the singular or plural?

Tags: grammar

Two cups of tea _______ (is or are) enough for me.

Comment: Hi @Mary.  This type of question is better suited to our sister site, for people who are learning English - http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Dunno, @MaxWilliams - it might be more complex than a learner's issue. On the one hand, "two cups" is clearly plural so "are" would seem correct, but on the other hand "two cups of tea" could be taken as a singular noun phrase, equivalent to "having two cups", in which case "is" would be correct. Any grammarians able to advise further on this?

Comment: @Chappo Well, I think you nailed it. It depends on how you perceive "two cups of tea". If it is conceived as a total amount you take a day, I don't see any reason why you can't use "is".

Comment: There have been a lot of questions addressing 'logical/notional agreement'. I'd use 'Two cups of tea were on the table' but 'Ten cups of tea in a morning is too much'. cf 'Ten miles is too far to swim'.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I surched all of the grammar books which no comments about the phrase to be the subject in the sentence. Another similar one question is : Two kilos of beef is enough for us. Is it a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. If you consider "two cups of tea" as a single entity, you can use "is". However, if you are thinking of the number of cups, you can use "are".